# Keeping date class when changing date format?

Tags: r

I know this subject was asked often but I can't find a solution. I try to change the class to date and in a format, that is used by everyone in the group so their code can still run.
I have dates and I want them in the format dd-mm-yyyy. For example:

```
df <- data.frame(date=c("31.08.2011", "31.07.2011", "30.06.2011", "30.06.2011"), num=as.numeric(c("3","6","9", "4")))
```

Now the class is Factor. Plotting is working with

```
plot(num ~ date, data = aggregate(num~date, data=df, sum), type = "b")
```

When I try to change them to date class with

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%d.%m.%Y")
```

the class now is date, but the format is always yyyy-mm-dd, but due to plotting elsewhere in the code specified dates in the code not the one I need. Another approach is

```
df$date <- as.POSIXct(df$date, "%d.%m.%Y")
df$date <- strftime(df$date,"%d.%m.%Y")
```

In this case, the requested format is given, but the class changes to character and plotting is not working. 
From my readings I should reach my goal already with my first approach. Is it impossible to keep the date class and change the format?

Any help is welcome. 
Best regards!

Comment: After `df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%d.%m.%Y")`, plot works on my end, but you mentioned: `the class now is date, but the format is always yyyy-mm-dd, but due to plotting elsewhere in the code specified dates in the code not the one I need`. Then what exactly you need?

Comment: If you need the dates displayed in a different format, consider using `ggplot2` which lets you define any date format in the plot while keeping the underlying data formatted as dates. `df=data.frame(x = Sys.Date() + 1:10, y = 1:10); library(ggplot2); ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() + scale_x_date(date_labels = "%d.%m.%Y")`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. @Sixiang.Hu In the code, plotting is specified for certain dates (for example     `plot(df$num[df$date=="31.08.2011"])`. When I now try to format it df$date shows 2011-08-31, so the old plot function doesn't work anymore. So far it seems like I can't make it a date without the need to change all the `plot(df$num[df$date=="31.08.2011"])` to `plot(df$num[df$date=="2011-08-31"])`, right?

Comment: @docendodiscimus That is a good looking way, but I still would need to change all the dates in the code.